# simple html dom parser -> find "conditions"

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

i have problem with parse from website with simple html dom parser.. i try to parse code like this:

```
<li>
 <p class="x"></p><p>..</p> <p>..</p> <p>..</p>
 <p class="x"></p><p>..</p> <p>..</p> <p>..</p>
 <p class="x"></p><p>..</p> <p>..</p> <p>..</p>
</li>
```

my goal is to save these paragraphs separated.
For paragraphs with class definition is easy, like `$year = $class->find(p[class=x]');` but i need parse the others too. How can i save to another array only paragraphs without class specification without paragraphs with class?

Comment: What language are you using? PHP?

Comment: yep, including ("simple_html_dom.php")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in the `find` method, so filter after:

```
$year = $class->find('p');
// filter out nodes with empty class properties
$without = array_filter($year, function($v) { return empty($v->class); });

// since array_filter preserves keys
$with = array_diff_key($year, $without);

// or filter again checking that class is NOT empty
$with = array_filter($year, function($v) { return !empty($v->class); });
```